Confusion regarding repeated wedge product
I am learning about the wedge product an recently found an exercise stating that in $\bigwedge^2(\bigwedge^2 \mathbb{R^4}):$
$$(e_1 \wedge e_2 + e_3 \wedge e_4) \wedge (e_1 \wedge e_2 + e_3 \wedge e_4) \neq 0$$
Where $e_i$ denotes an element of the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R^4}$. This left me wondering since I thought we could simplify such an expression via the alternating and bilinear property of the wedge product:
$$(e_1 \wedge e_2 + e_3 \wedge e_4) \wedge (e_1 \wedge e_2 + e_3 \wedge e_4) = \\
(e_1 \wedge e_2) \wedge (e_1 \wedge e_2) + (e_1 \wedge e_2) \wedge (e_3 \wedge e_4) + \\(e_3 \wedge e_4) \wedge (e_1 \wedge e_2) + (e_3 \wedge e_4) \wedge (e_3 \wedge e_4) = \\
0 + (e_1 \wedge e_2) \wedge (e_3 \wedge e_4) - (e_1 \wedge e_2) \wedge (e_3 \wedge e_4)+ 0 = 0$$
Is there an error in my calculations maybe due to the repeated wedging?

It's $(e_3 \wedge e_4) \wedge (e_1 \wedge e_2) = e_3 \wedge e_4 \wedge e_1 \wedge e_2 = e_1 \wedge e_2 \wedge e_3 \wedge e_4$ because each single exchange incurs a minus sign, so double exchanges don't affect the result.

Basis products of even length commute with a basis vector and so the do with anything. It's one of the reasons why in $\mathbb R^3$ so many operations work if one preserves the signature, or as one says in physics courses, alway follow the  right hand side.

@Mason thanks for the quick correction. I did not recall we can use the "associativity" in the first step you did

Are you sure that the exercise says $\wedge^2(\wedge^2 \mathbb{R}^4)$ and not $\wedge^4\mathbb{R}^4$? I believe in $\wedge^2(\wedge^2 \mathbb{R}^4)$ what you write in the question is correct, but if we work in $\wedge^4\mathbb{R}^4$ then @Mason's comment is correct.

@VladimirLysikov Thank you for your remark. I looked it up and it indeed says $\wedge^4 \mathbb{R}^4$. What exactly is the difference in calculations since I thought them to be isomorphic?

They are very different, they don't even have the same dimension. (One is 15 and the other is 1!) In ${\bigwedge}V$ what you know is that $v\wedge v = 0$ for $v$ in $V$. That doesn't say anything about any other element of ${\bigwedge}V$. In ${\bigwedge}^4\mathbb R^4$ we have $V=\mathbb R^4$, but in ${\bigwedge}^2({\bigwedge}^2\mathbb R^4)$ we have $V={\bigwedge}^2\mathbb R^4$. This latter case is no different from ${\bigwedge}^2\mathbb R^6$; the internal structure of $V$ doesn't matter, all that matters is that it is a vector space.

$\wedge^4 \mathbb{R}^4$ consists of 4-wedges, and $a \wedge b \wedge c \wedge d$ changes sign every time two vectors are swapped (but not blocks of vectors, so we have $a\wedge b\wedge c \wedge d=-c\wedge b\wedge a\wedge d=c\wedge d\wedge a\wedge b$). $\wedge^2\wedge^2\mathbb{R}^4$ is the space of 2-wedges of 2-wedges, so they change signs whenever 2 vectors in the left wedge are swapped, or 2 vectors in right wedge, but also when 2 wedges in the outer wedge are swapped: $[a\wedge b]\wedge [c\wedge d]=-[b\wedge a]\wedge [c\wedge d]=-[a\wedge b]\wedge [d\wedge c]=-[c\wedge d]\wedge [a\wedge b]$

Thank you! Now it should be clear.

$\Lambda^2(\Lambda^2(\mathbb{R}^4))$ and $\Lambda^4(\mathbb{R}^4)$ are quite different as Vladimir says, and the answer is that the exercise is correct for $\Lambda^4$ but that you are correct for $\Lambda^2(\Lambda^2)$ (so $\Lambda^4$ is likely what was intended). The argument in $\Lambda^2(\Lambda^2)$ can also be done more simply: by definition we have $v \wedge v = 0$ for any $v \in \Lambda^2$. (There is an unpleasant notational issue here too, in $\Lambda^2(\Lambda^2)$ we really should denote the "inner" and "outer" wedge products by different symbols to avoid confusion, and in particular to avoid confusion with working in $\Lambda^4$.)
One additional possible source of confusion here is that the wedge product $\Lambda^2 \otimes \Lambda^2 \to \Lambda^4$ is symmetric, not antisymmetric, so it actually descends to a map $S^2(\Lambda^2) \to \Lambda^4$ from the symmetric square of the exterior square to $\Lambda^4$.
